# Please help me proving that the sum is harmonic

Tags: banach-spaces

If ${c_n}$ is a bounded sequence, then
$$
f(r, \theta)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_nr^{|n|}e^{in\theta}
$$
is harmonic in the disc.

Help me proving?

Comment: 1) Show that each term is harmonic. 2) Show the Laplacian of the sum is the sum of the Laplacian.

Comment: What disk? Do you mean unit disk?

Comment: yes, a unit disc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f'_r=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty |n|c_nr^{|n|-1}e^{in\theta}\;,\;\;f''_{rr}=\sum_{-\infty}^\infty |n|\,(|n|-1)c_n\,r^{|n|-2}e^{in\theta}$$

$$f'_\theta=i\sum_{-\infty}^\infty n\,c_nr^{|n|}e^{in\theta}\;,\;\;\;f''_{\theta\theta}=-\sum_{-\infty}^\infty n^2\,c_nr^{|n|}e^{in\theta}$$

So Laplace's equation in polar coordinates:

$$r^2f''_{rr}+rf'_r+f''_{\theta\theta}=\ldots$$

And now you have to prove the above is zero...

**Spoiler!:**

> $$\sum_{-\infty}^\infty \;c_n\left(|n|\,(|n|-1)+|n|-n^2\right)r^{|n|}e^{in\theta}=0$$

Comment: Thanks sir, is this detailed solution

Comment: Well, it *almost* is, @MatemaTika, yet you should first try **hard** to reach it after reading some hints. That's the best way to learn...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In complex form your sum is $c_0 + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} c_nz^n + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} c_n\bar{z}^n$. Write this as a real part of an analytic function on the unit disc. (By the way, I'm assuming the $c_n$ are real, otherwise it's not necessarily a real-valued function).

Comment: thanks sir, but can you solving detalais please